# android database to oracle database

Tags: android, database, oracle, synchronization, data-transfer

Can someone give me an idea or point me in the right direction about following matter:

I need to make android app that will do some things with remote oracle database (take some data, insert some data, ...).

I can do that, but the trick is, app owner needs to be able to do that **offline** (because he doesn't have internet everywhere), then when user connects to internet, somehow transfer those offline changes in local android database to oracle database.
I never did something like that.Any pointers?

Should I make same database structure in android database like that remote oracle database?Then somehow synchronize changes?
Or is it done some other way?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the ability, it would be best to create a RESTful application on the server that listens for your app to contact it. Then it would take the data (send it from your app via JSON, XML or any of several other popular formats) and operate directly on the Oracle database by doing the adds/inserts/deletes there.

You can do the same thing on the way down - your app contacts the server, the server provides data from the database in the form of JSON, XML, etc and your app can then operate on it's own internal JAVA objects of data.